# I can't get the output for the vector

Tags: vector, output

Supposedly,this program allows us to store data into the vector.We can keep on entering integers and then the program terminates when there is a non-integer.The program is supposed to print the largest value entered.
****however when I run this code below,I can only keep on entering the integers.And when I enter a non-integer,it gives a list of errors.

My code is(I'm not sure if Im running it correctly):

```
package javaapplication58;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class JavaApplication58 {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Vector <Integer> v=new Vector();
            v=readInVectorOfIntegers();
            System.out.println(largest(v));

           }
        public static Vector  <Integer> readInVectorOfIntegers()
        {Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Vector<Integer>w=new Vector ();
        while (in.hasNextLine())w.addElement(in.nextInt());
        return w;

        }

        public static int largest(Vector <Integer> v)
        {int largestsofar;
        if(v.size()>0){largestsofar=v.elementAt(0);
        for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
            if(largestsofar<v.elementAt(i))
             largestsofar=v.elementAt(i);
        return largestsofar;


        }

        return 0;


        }
    }
```

Comment: OMGG I just realised my mistake hahaha